# ActionListener buttons only works for login or register, not both

Tags: java, swing, sockets, actionlistener, distributed-system

I'm making an echo server in java, I have two buttons one for registration and one for login, I can login OR register but after that to use the other function I need to reopen the program.

When I create an account & try to log in with it I get the following error:
`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "s" is null`.

I tried to debug the program to find where "s" is null, but without success.
I can't understand why functions work if used only once and stop working if used together

My functions:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        createInterface();       
    }
```

```
public static void createInterface() throws IOException{
        
        var ip = "localhost";
        var port = 8080;
        Socket socket = new Socket(ip, port);
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        
        
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        JLabel login = new JLabel("  Login");
        JLabel username = new JLabel("User:");
        JLabel password = new JLabel("Pass:");
        JTextPane usernameBox = new JTextPane();
        JPasswordField passwordBox = new JPasswordField();
        JButton botaoCadastro = new JButton("Register");
        JButton botaoLogin = new JButton("Login");
        
        
        botaoLogin.setBounds(100, 140, 100, 40);
        botaoCadastro.setBounds(100, 190, 100, 40);
        usernameBox.setBounds(110, 55, 75, 25);  
        passwordBox.setBounds(110, 95, 75, 25);  
        login.setBounds(110, 1, 75, 75);
        username.setBounds(60, 55, 75, 25);
        password.setBounds(68, 95, 75, 25);
        login.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman",Font.BOLD,20));
        
        
        f.add(botaoLogin);
        f.add(botaoCadastro);
        f.add(login);
        f.add(username);
        f.add(password);        
        f.add(usernameBox);          
        f.add(passwordBox);
        
        botaoLogin.addActionListener((ActionListener) new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            @SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {try {;
                        String username = usernameBox.getText(); 
                        char[] passwordChar = passwordBox.getPassword(); 
                        String password = String.valueOf(passwordChar);
                        
                        boolean success = login(writer, reader, username, password);
                        if (success){
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "login authorized", "Login", 1);
                        }else{
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect username or password", "Login", 1);
                        }
                        
                      
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
        
        botaoCadastro.addActionListener((ActionListener) new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    String username = usernameBox.getText(); 
                    char[] passwordChar = passwordBox.getPassword(); 
                    String password = String.valueOf(passwordChar); 
                    
                    int success = register(writer, reader, username, password);
                    switch (success) {
                        case 0 -> JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "registration done", "Register", 1);
                        case 1 -> JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User already exists", "Register", 1);
                        case 2 -> JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "blank user field", "Register", 1);
                        default -> JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "?????", "Register", 1);
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
                    
        });
        
        f.setSize(300,300);  
        f.setLayout(null); 
        f.setVisible(true);  
   
    }
```

```
public static boolean login(OutputStreamWriter writer,BufferedReader reader, String username, String password) throws IOException{
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("protocolo", "100");
        jsonObject.put("username", username); 
        jsonObject.put("password", password); 
        writer.write(jsonObject.toString() + "\n");
        writer.flush();
        String line = reader.readLine();
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(line);
        System.out.println("[LOGIN] sent to server: " + jsonObject.toString(2));
        String loginLine = reader.readLine();
        JSONObject loginAnswer = new JSONObject(loginLine);
        reader.readLine();
        System.out.println(loginAnswer);
        if (loginAnswer.getString("protocolo").equals("101")) { 
            System.out.println("Login successful");
            return true;
        }else{
            System.out.println("login not authorized, username or password incorrect");
            return false;
        }
    }
    
        public static int register(OutputStreamWriter writer,BufferedReader reader, String username, String password) throws IOException{
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("protocolo", "300");
        jsonObject.put("username", username); 
        jsonObject.put("password", password); 
        writer.write(jsonObject.toString() + "\n");
        writer.flush();
        String line2 = reader.readLine();
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(line2);
        System.out.println("[REGISTER] sent to server: " + jsonObject.toString(2));
        String registerLine = reader.readLine();
        JSONObject registerAnswer = new JSONObject(registerLine);
        reader.readLine();
        System.out.println(registerAnswer);
        
        if (registerAnswer.getString("protocolo").equals("301")) {
            System.out.println("register successful");
            return 0;
        }else if (registerAnswer.getString("protocolo").equals("302")) {
            System.out.println("user already exists");
            return 1;
        }else if (registerAnswer.getString("protocolo").equals("303")) {
            System.out.println("field empty");
            return 2;
        }else{
            System.out.println("unk protocol");
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

**any** help is welcome :))

Edit: full error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "s" is null
    at java.base/java.io.StringReader.<init>(StringReader.java:51)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.<init>(JSONTokener.java:94)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:421)
    at network.Client.login(Client.java:39)
    at network.Client$1.actionPerformed(Client.java:129)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6626)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3389)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6391)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5001)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: Swing threading may be contributing to some problems, but the NullPointerException issue remains difficult for any of us to help with, without your posting the stacktrace and indicating which line throws the exception (as per *most* NPE questions -- please read: [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)).

Comment: I added the stacktrace and I'm reading the post about NPE!

Comment: So, the key question is: *what line is `Client.java:39`*? The first line from the stack trace that shows the error emanating from your code is: `at network.Client.login(Client.java:39)`

Comment: Side note: you don't appear to be using your Logger library to its full extent. You should be logging much more information, especially in the code *before* the NPE is thrown to see what the state of the key variables are in the code. You can always change the logging level when you no longer have this error.

Comment: Line 39 is jsonObject = new JSONObject(line); @HovercraftFullOfEels ,I  will try to implement the Logger library to get more information about the error

Comment: so `line` is likely null on that line. Now you should do some debugging to find out why.

Comment: So, I removed all the "network" related code and your code works "fine", without error, so the issue is with the response from server, instead of doing `jsonObject = new JSONObject(line);` immediately, I'd recommend dumping `line` to stdout to see what is been returned

Comment: I just tested it and indeed `String line = reader.readLine();` is returning null.
I will analyze the server, apparently his response never arrives for the Client to read.